# Where is the documentation for the ruby -run command-line parameter?

Tags: ruby

```
$ ruby -run -e httpd . -p 3000
```

The `-run` option is not listed in the help text (`ruby --help`). I haven't been able to find any documentation on this option.

Comment: There's no "-run" option. It's just `-r un`

Comment: You should learn [the difference between `--` and `-`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/single-dashes-for-single-character-options-but-double-dashes-for-words) when specifying command line arguments, it will make your interactions with the command line seem much saner.

Answer (score 4):

This is the same as

```
$ ruby -r un -e httpd . -p 3000
```

i.e. use the `-r` option to require the [`un` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/un/rdoc/index.html) before executing your code.

The `un` library [contains](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/un.rb) “Utilities to replace common UNIX commands in Makefiles etc”. It looks like the docs aren’t being picked up properly for the current version, possibly because of an [incorrectly added `nodoc` tag](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/ed0cba79ca34fa67c4f4d76bdb03391a12b2c5b6). The [Ruby 2.0.0 docs are available](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/un/rdoc/Object.html).

Comment: `ruby -run -e help` provides some documentation

Comment: Seems like a `:nodoc:` statement breaks the current documentation. The [`un` docs for 2.0.0](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/un/rdoc/Object.html) are working.

Comment: Back before RubyGems was added to Ruby, the RubyGems developers shipped a wrapper library called `ubygems.rb`, which would allow you to run `ruby -rubygems` in order to use Gems.

Comment: @Stefan good spot. It looks like the [intention was to only prevent documentation of the `setup` method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/ed0cba79ca34fa67c4f4d76bdb03391a12b2c5b6).